# How to update documents from firebase functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm triggering a function on a document change and i need to update another one but I'm having an error.

I'm having the same error when try to read one document.

I have deleted every package except firebase-admin, firebase-functions

I have restored my code to only one function.

```
/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/index.js:28
async function request(opts) {
      ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js:18:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
```

I expect to update the document or to retrieve a document, butI'im having that error. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: please show us your code. you have a syntax error

Comment: which node version do you use?

Comment: I'm using Node v10.15.3

`
exports.helloWorld = functions.firestore.document('test/{id}').onCreate((event, context) => {
    return admin.firestore().collection('test2').add(event.data())
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);

        })
})
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're using a older version of Node. Async functions are not supported by Node versions older than version 7.6.

If you want to use async/await then you need to transpile using Babel for your node version.

Comment: I'm using Node -10.15.3